# Ajax change to JSON (Jquery offline + Manifest) - Offline web application

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, html

I want to do the offline web application.

So I'm changing the Ajax to JSON in using [JQuery offline](https://github.com/wycats/jquery-offline).

Ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: contentpage,
  data: contentpagedata,
  cache: false
}).done(function( html ) {
    contentf=''+html;

           $("#ajaxcontent").empty().append(contentf).fadeIn(500);
           $("#submenu-content").empty().append(topf).fadeIn(500);
           alert(contentpage);
    }
});
```

Try to replace by JSON:

```
var updateArticles = function(callback) {
  alert(contentpage);
$.retrieveJSON(contentpage, {data: contentpagedata}, function(json, status) {
    alert("123");
  var contentf = $("#ajaxcontentTemplate").render( json );

           $("#ajaxcontent").empty().append(contentf).fadeIn(500);


});
};
```

Anyone has idea on this? Besides, should I create a .json or .rb files...etc? Also, is the Manifest file able to cache the dynamic files like .PHP??

Comment: dynamic files cant be cached with `HTML5`

Answer (score 0):

Manifest cache can be used only for caching static resources. For dynamic resources,
use WEBSQL. Although WEBSQL is phased out, if you are targeting your app for mobile then i would suggest you to use WEBSQL as well as IndexDB.